# Why are the file names coming with an extra single quote at the beginning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, filenames

I am trying to dynamically name my output files in df.to_excel as shown below:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\excel_outputs\'Solved'+str(f), index = False)
```

Also, str(f) contains my input file name and changes every time. The resulting filenames I'm getting are:

```
'Solvedsheet1
'Solvedsheet2
'Solvedsheet3
```

I just want:

```
Solvedsheet1
Solvedsheet2
Solvedsheet3
```

Comment: Should be df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\excel_outputs\Solved'+str(f), index = False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a single string, so....

```
f = 'sheet1'
x = r"C:\Users\excel_outputs\Solved"+str(f)
print(x)
```

Result....

```
C:\Users\excel_outputs\Solvedsheet1
```